# Isabelle: Class of topological vector spaces

Tags: isabelle

I wanted to define the class of topological vector spaces in the obvious way:

```
theory foo
imports Real_Vector_Spaces 
begin

class topological_vector = topological_space + real_vector +
  assumes add_cont_fst: "∀a. continuous_on UNIV (λb. a + b)"
  ...
```

but I got the error `Type inference imposes additional sort constraint topological_space of type parameter 'a of sort type`

I tried introducing type constraints in the condition, and it looks like 
`continuous_on` doesn't want to match with the default type `'a` of the class.

Of course I can work around this by replacing continuity with equivalent conditions, I'm just curious why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a class definition in Isabelle/HOL, there may occur only one type variable (namely `'a`), which has the default HOL sort `type`. Thus, one cannot formalise multi-parameter type classes. This also affects definitions *inside* type classes, which may depend only on the parameters of one type class. For example, you can define a predicate `cont :: 'a set => ('a => 'a) => bool` inside the type class context `topological_space` as follows

```
definition (in topological_space) cont :: "'a set ⇒ ('a ⇒ 'a) ⇒ bool"
where "cont s f = (∀x∈s. (f ---> f x) (at x within s))"
```

The target `(in topological_space)` tells the type class system that `cont` really depends only on one type. Thus, it is safe to use `cont` in assumptions of other type classes which inherit from `topological_space`.

Now, the predicate `continuous_on` in Isabelle/HOL has the type `'a set => ('a => 'b) => bool` where both `'a` and `'b` must be of sort `topological_space`. Thus, `continuous_on` is more general than `cont`, because it allows different topological spaces `a` and `b`. Conversely, `continuous_on` cannot be defined within any *one* type class. Consequently, you cannot use `continuous_on` in assumptions of type classes either. This restriction is not specific to `continuous_on`, it appears for all kinds of morphisms, e.g. `mono` for order-preserving functions, homomorphisms between algebraic structures, etc. Single-parameter type classes just cannot express such things.

In your example, you get the error because Isabelle unifies all occuring type variables to `'a` and then realises that `continuous_on` forces the sort `topological_space` on `'a`, but for the above reasons, you may not depend on sorts in class specifications.

Nevertheless, there might be a simple way out. Just define `cont` as described above and use it in the assumptions of `topological_vector` instead of `continuous_on`. Outside of the class context, you can then prove that `cont = continuous_on` and derive the original assumption with `continuous_on` instead of `cont`.  This keeps you from reasoning abstractly within the class context, but this is only a minor restriction.

Comment: Thanks. So, if understand correctly, I can't use any constant in the class specification, that already has a class constrain on its type variables, even if the new class happens to be a subclass of the constaining class (topological_space in this case). I assumed that Isabelle will figure out that `continuous_on` is safe to use here, because from the expression it can infer that `'a` and `'b` must be the same, and `'a` happens to be a topological space.

Comment: Inside a class specification or class context, the type variable `'a` always has sort `type`, no matter what the superclasses are. This is due to the implementation of classes on top of locales, which manage the assumptions, definitions, and theorems inside a class context.